# Locking Namespace but leave one page unlocked

Tags: mediawiki

I am attempting to lock my entire "Help" namespace from being edited by non admins. I would, however, like to whitelist one page so that non-admins can edit it. This one page is the support desk.

So far, in my `LocalSettings.php` file I have:

```
 $wgNamespaceProtection[NS_HELP] = array( 'admins-edit' );
 $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['admins-edit'] = true;
```

This successfully is preventing non-admins from editing any page in the Help namespace. What I cannot figure out how to do is whitelist one page (called "Help:Support Desk").

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Preventing_Access#Restrict_editing_of_all_but_a_few_pages

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't do it, move it outside the namespace to Project:Support_Desk ...

Answer (score 0):

So after your code you need to do:

`$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = False;`

`$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = False;`

that disallows any user from seeing anything.

You then do:

`$wgWhitelistRead = array("Main Page", etc.)`

That whitelists certain pages and not whole namespaces, though I can't find a way of whitelisting both at the same time.